# Переход по коду

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, может я покажусь делитантом. Но по другому я даже не знаю как описать такой вопрос.

У нас есть гиганская функция по расчету кучу значений. В начале функции принимается много констант и значений, но одна из переменных будет посчитано ближе к концу функции. Получается что оно в начале неизвестно. Неизвестность этого числа в момент прохода функции не как не повлияет на его расчет. но многие переменные  в момент его обьявления и его вычеслением высчитываются с учетом этой переменной, но получим значение его только под конец функции. Вопрос, нам надо получить значение переменной в начале, которое расчитается примерно к концу функции. Все происходит в пределе блока одной функции.
В свифте есть такая штука, мы пишим код и опа нам надо перепрыгнуть кучу строк(не помню как она вызывается"Буду благодарен если кто напомнит"), мы пишим комануду перехода к ключу кода (B), помечая где в коде это место. И переходим к месту поменичным ключем (B), если нам возвращатся назад не надо, то ничего не пишем, а если надо  вернуться обратно то пишем этот код перехода к ключу (A), но также прописываем место где этот ключ (A). Если указать его перед прыжком к ключу B или не закрыть код перехода от повтроного его прохода к строке перехода к ключу (B) то программа зацыклится.
При этом все изменения переменных, тех которые не внутри внутренних блоков, обьявленных в начале держутся в памяти.
Грубо говоря, бежим все высчитываем, тут стави команду перехода, чтоб дважды не проходить закрываем ифом, чтобы попасть один раз. Возвращаемся в начало, уже со знанием этой переменной, и расчитываем все заново.

Как это реализовать на С++.

Comment: мне кажется, это следствие плохой архитектуры функции, разбейте её на мелкие и/или поменяйте местами порядок вычислений. Конкретно по вопросу - `goto` но это не приветствуется.

Comment: *"Неизвестность этого числа в момент прохода функции не как не повлияет на его расчет. но многие переменные в момент его объявления и его вычислением высчитываются с учетом этой переменной"* — что это значит? У вас есть cсходящийся итеративный процесс, который не чувствителен к начальному значению одной из переменных?

Comment: Да я понимаю, это грубая ошибка, и не качественное написание, это я понимаю. Писал бы сам такого не допустил бы, а переписать нельзя. Поэтому приходится прибегать к такой манипуляции.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы привели хрестоматийный пример отвратительнейшего кода в стиле "лапша" - огромная простыня из вычислений, которая непонятно как работает. И при этом, вы хотите сделать ситуацию еще хуже, залепив туда переход по метке.

Правильный подход состоит в грамотном структурировании вашего куска кода.

Структурное программирование изобрел [Э. Дейкстра](http://samag.ru/uart/more/16) специально для таких "умников", которые иначе как потоком сознания программировать не умеют. Он же написал отличное объяснение тому, [почему GOTO надо отправить на помойку](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Considered_harmful) вместе с программистами, которые его используют. И даже вместе с программистами, которые используют его вместо обработки исключений.

Comment: Я понимаю все это. Но код не мой и меня попросили глобального его не править. Я когда его получил высказался точно как и вы, но попросили нечего не трогать, прям как в анекдоте про сына программиста.

Comment: @JoMax: я так понимаю *любое изменение* в этой функции может внести баг, который вы не сможете предсказать (из-за convoluted структуры). Использование goto породит баги ещё успешней.  Поэтому не надо боятся радикально её упростить, применяя лучшие практики, которые вероятно стали преобладающими ещё до рождения ваших родителей. Естественно, следует тщательно тестировать все изменения (написать новые тесты, если их нет и/или расширить старые тесты). Можно понять логику, когда люди сопротивляются полному переписыванию кривых, но рабочих проектов. Эта логика не относится к *отдельным функциям*.

Comment: Вы правы, я щас прохожу в отладки пока, смотрю не появились баги? после использования, как бы выразится недопустимой процедуры goto. Но если выскочит хотя бы один баг, я непременно буду переписывать. Спасибо за очень хороший совет. @jfs

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, вы хотите применить связку `setjmp/longjmp`. Но это желание говорит об одном - о низком качестве кода. Переделайте его нормально, и учтите, что классики - тот же Страуструп - дают очень неплохой совет: **исходный текст одной функции должен помещаться на один экран**. Иначе - это плохо продуманная функция.

Программирование - это не только кодирование, но еще и проектирование.

Comment: Как я отписался уже под каждым. Я с вами полностью согласен и при виде этого кода высказывал свое мнение также как и вы мне сейчас говорите. Но меня просили его не менять глобально, а просто добавить некоторые вещи в определенные места.